# Sorting results in Elastic

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Trying to sort query results now. Neither of the queries below works:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

even though they seem to be valid, according to the ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort.html)). What am I missing here? And by the way, does the order of query parts matters at all in Elastic?

Comment: What do you mean by "works" and "not works"? Is your `name` property analyzed (please paste relevant mapping snippet)? Your syntax is indeed correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have faced same case.If your name field mapped as string and anlayzed then query never works. Use multi field type where you can map name twice, one as string and analyzed and another as string and not analyzed. For Ex

```
'user_id' =>array('type'=>'integer'),
'name' =>array(
     'type'=>'multi_field',
     'fields'=>array(
          'name'=>array('type'=>'string','index'=>'analyzed'),
          'sort_name'=>array('type'=>'string','index'=> 'not_analyzed')
      )
   )
```

using above mapping, you can search on name field and u can sort using sort_name.

```
{
 'query': {
  'query_string':{'query':'user_name*','fields':['name']}
  },
  'sort':[
  {
    'name.sort_name': {
    'order': 'asc'
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

Reference Link :
1) http://awesomism.co.uk/536336#
2) http://blog.wiercinski.net/2011/uncategorized/elasticsearch-sorting-on-string-types-with-more-than-one-value-per-doc-or-more-than-one-token-per-field/